# How to get an input from a user and check if it matches a variable without the user having direct access to the variable?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to have a web page that accepts a user's input and checks that it matches another variable and return either a true or false value. It needs to be secure so that the user cannot find the value so for example the values can't be hard coded. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Start with writing some code to get value and share it with us

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
**SO is not** a free Coding service ___We try to fix your code, we do not write your code___

Comment: Have a look at *hashes*

Comment: Have an input form, send/post it to server via XHR, do all the checks on the server and return true if true ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

    $valueFROMuser = $_POST['userValue'];

    $serverValue = "somevalue";

    if ($valueFROMuser !== $serverValue) {

        echo "does not match";
    } else {

        echo "match";

        //do something
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well If you already know the value and it's static you may place it in a button's onclick event and return false.

```
<input type='text' id='a' />
<input type='button' onclick='return check()'>
```

Use this in javascript.

```
<script>
function check(){
var a = 2; //assuming 2 is the value you need the textbox's text to be compared with
var b = document.getElementById('a').value;
if(a!=b){
alert('Value does not match.');
return false
}
}
</script>
```